# Changing program associations

Tags: windows, windows-registry, file-associations

We currently have two versions of an application (CS3 and CS4) on our XP build. It defaults to the wrong version (CS4) when opening documents.

What registry changes do we need to make to change the defaults?  (Or a similar scriptable fix)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This [InformIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27561&seqNum=3) article should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

All the Windows file association information is stored under:

```
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

Each file type has its own key under here, so you would need to write a script to update the key for every type CS works with.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pretty [detailed answer](https://superuser.com/questions/22933/what-program-do-you-use-to-edit-file-associations-in-vista-and-windows-7/22979#22979) on SuperUser for a similar question.  Although I got modded down there for being too complicated it seems.  But it does have all the info you'd need to script a direct registry fix for file associations.  If people want, I can repost the text here.